# How to write/read to DIO port using C#

Tags: c#, io, port

[image: excerpt from PC specification]

Hello!
I need an advice to start working with the DIO port on the [tBOX810-838-FL](http://www.axiomtek.com/Default.aspx?MenuId=Products&FunctionId=ProductView&ItemId=8903&upcat=264) using C#. I need to switch on/off the relay from my app. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read user manual? : http://www.axiomtek.com/Download/download/tBOX810-838-FL/tBOX810-838-FL%20User's%20Manual%20VA2_03-27-2017.pdf  It has a Lan connector so you can use TCP to send messages.  What operating system is installed?

Comment: OS: Windows10. There is only pinout configuration described in this manual.

Comment: It says TTL output.  So you have 8 bits that can be programmed to 0V or 5V.  So go to Digikey and find a relay driver that take a TTL input.  Then get a voltage supply that matches the relay coil voltage (5V, 12V, 24V, 28V).

Comment: Ok! But how I can access them through the windows app?

Comment: I don't know enough about the software in machine to give answer.  I was going to ask you the same question.  Does the vendor have a compiler?  Can you set bits though a command line like in normal windows cmd.exe?  Have you tried to use there help in cmd.exe to see is a command?